# Php код в css в частности в background-image

Tags: php, html, css

Добрый вечер. 
Столкнулся с проблемой интеграции слайдера. 
Слайдер написан так, что картинка выводится в background-image: url(...);

При интеграции необходимо автоматизировать процесс подставления картинки из движка, есть такая php функция которая подставляет путь к картинке:

```
<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"
```

Естественно если вставить ее в background-image: url(...);

То ничего не произойдёт.

Пытался переводить в html, получается вот так:

```
&lt;?=$arItem[&quot;PREVIEW_PICTURE&quot;][&quot;SRC&quot;]?&gt;
```

Но так тоже не работает из-за ";".

Скажите пожалуйста есть ли какой то способ подставить сие чудо в стиль? 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: > Естественно если вставить ее в `background-image: url(...);`, то ничего не произойдёт.

Вообще-то не очень естественно, все должно нормально работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря странный вопрос, но всё же напишу своё мнение. У вас пару вариантов:

```
<div style="background-image:url('<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>');">
     Some content
</div>
```

А ещё есть совсем "хипстерский" его не рекомендую но это работает :)

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
          var picData  =  '<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>';
          var newStyle =  '<style>';
          var newStyle =+ '.myclass { background-image:url("' + picData + '"); }';
          var newStyle =+ '</style>';
          $('head').append(newStyle );
     });
</script>
```